# Get Alpha Value Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement, alpha, nsbox

How would I get the alpha value of a NSBox and Use it in an if statement?

I want to check the alpha of an NSBox if the value is equal to 0 then do something.

```
if ([Preferences alphaValue ==0]) {
        [[[[Preferences subviews] objectAtIndex:0] animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];

    } else {
        [[[[Preferences subviews] objectAtIndex:0] animator] setAlphaValue:1];

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you want

```
if ([Preferences alphaValue] == 1.0)
```

or something?

You need to explain what you want to do more clearly.

Comment: Yes.  I want to check the alpha of an NSBox if the value is equal to 0 then do something.

Comment: @s0ulp1xel: well just check if your value == 0...? I must be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

`if ([PreferencesButton state]== 0) {`

```
    [[[[Preferences subviews] objectAtIndex:0] animator] setAlphaValue:0.0];

} else {

    [[[[Preferences subviews] objectAtIndex:0] animator] setAlphaValue:1];
}
```

I was using a toggle button and need to use the state of the button instead of the alpha of the preferences box.

Answer (score 0):

`[Preferences alpha] == 0.0f`

Should be what you're looking for